# Using CONVERT with a data table column in dynamic SQL

Tags: sql-server, dynamic-sql

I have the following dynamic query to check if today's date is between the `FTOStartDate` and `FTOEndDDate` from a data table.

I am getting the following errors:

> *Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 18
>
>   Invalid column name 'FTOStartDate'.
>
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 19
>
>   Invalid column name 'FTOEndDate'.*

All the examples I looked at used a variable in the convert function; I need to use a column name from the data table.

Thanks,
Brad

```
SET @env = dbo.GetSQLEnvironment();
SET @assigned_claim_table = 'grp_clm_ops_d' + @env + '.dbo.cauDCMFToAssign';

SET @sql = 'SELECT DCMNumber,  FTOStartDate ' + 
           'FROM ' + @assigned_claim_table + ' ' +
           'WHERE '  + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 110) + 
           ' NOT BETWEEN ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), FTOStartDate, 110) + 
           'AND ' +  CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), FTOEndDate, 110) + ' '

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

Comment: To avoid *any* potential problems with language and/or regional settings, I would recommend using the ISO date format - `CONVERT` style no. 112 - instead of the 110 style which is US-specific (and will **break** on most European SQL Server instances)

Comment: @marc_s or don't bother converting in the first place. I added an answer because it's way too involved for a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not do:

```
SET @sql = 'SELECT DCMNumber,  FTOStartDate ' + 
           'FROM ' + @assigned_claim_table + ' ' +
           'WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 110) NOT BETWEEN ' + 
           ' CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), FTOStartDate, 110) AND CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), FTOEndDate, 110)'
```

SQL Server has no issue running converts inside of a dynamic query.

Comment: +1 plus then you're doing the convert inside the scope of where those columns are actually defined - spot on!

Answer (score 0):

Without the underlying definitions, it would seem that the table named in @assigned_claim_table doesn't contain the columns FTOStartDate and FTOEndDate.

That said, even if the table did, the query will produce the wrong results because 110 is US format M/D/Y so the comparison wouldn't work correctly; ISO 112 would be correct.

Comment: No, the columns exist in the table. The problem is the SQL is being constructed as if the table exists at the outer scope, when those column references should actually be inside the string. Jim spotted it.

Comment: Fair. Beware of 110 though ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I realize you've already resolved the immediate issue, but I just wanted to add that if the columns in the table are of any date/time type, all of these conversions are absolutely unnecessary. You can just as easily do:

```
SET @sql = 'SELECT DCMNumber,  FTOStartDate FROM ' 
  + @assigned_claim_table 
  + ' WHERE GETDATE() NOT BETWEEN FTOStartDate AND FTOEndDate;';
```

If they're not date/time, then:

```
SET @sql = 'SELECT DCMNumber,  FTOStartDate FROM ' 
  + @assigned_claim_table 
  + ' WHERE GETDATE() NOT BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, FTOStartDate)
      AND CONVERT(DATETIME, FTOEndDate);';
```

If you're trying to strip time from the columns, safer to do this than string conversions to ambiguous formats:

```
SET @sql = 'SELECT DCMNumber,  FTOStartDate FROM ' 
  + @assigned_claim_table 
  + ' WHERE GETDATE() NOT BETWEEN DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, FTOStartDate)
      AND DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, FTOEndDate);';
```

Not that `BETWEEN` or `NOT BETWEEN` is a good idea anyway - like your 110 format, that is ambiguous and subject to misinterpretation.

- [What do BETWEEN and the devil have in common?](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common)